# use objects for storing data and be able to alter it using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a fishing game using JavaScript, the problem i encountered is to store the fishes caught by the player.

```
var fishStorage = {};
```

this will be the object which will store the data.

```
var fishStorage["player_id"] = {fish: "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd"}
```

is it possible to do add the Fish value dynamically? like

```
function(id){
 fishStorage[id].fish // .push?? 
}
```

if my question is not specific i can give more code explaining the fishing process.

and getting the data out is easy.. but appending is what confusing me, if anyone can please give a link to a documentation or any help with this i will be grateful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure you create an *Object* if you're trying to access a property from an `id` that doesn't exist yet

```
function addFish(id, val){
    if (!fishStorage[id])
        fishStorage[id] = {};
    fishStorage[id].fish = val;
}
```

---

A different implementation, depending on your desired output, may be

```
function addFish(id, val){
    if (!fishStorage[id])
        fishStorage[id] = {fish: val};
    else
        fishStorage[id].fish += ',' + val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a value dynamically:

```
fishStorage[id].fish = value;
```

If you want to append new value:

```
fishStorage[id].fish += "," + value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a object to it first. Just using `fishStorage[id].fish` will give you a error but if you divide into 2 steps like:

```
fishStorage[id] = {};
fishStorage[id].fish = 'foo';
```

Then it will work. You might want to add a check to be able to use it easyer. Like:

```
function(id){
    if (!fishStorage[id]) fishStorage[id] = {};
    fishStorage[id].fish = 'foo';
}
```